# Low inductance high torque motors

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, induction-motor, brushed-dc-motor

Internal inductance of motor windings reduces the response time of motors.

I was wondering if there exists a motor type which is both high torque and low inductance? Or in other words a motor which responds faster to instantaneous input while still providing similar torque to a standard motor?

Comment: T=L/R controls response time

Comment: if you're prepared to specify it, and bung a motor manufacturer a shed load of cash, they'd build one for you. Use a large air-gap, this will reduce inductance. Use high strength magnets, this will keep the B-field high for reasonable efficiency, but make it cost a lot more than standard, which is why you won't find a general purpose one off the shelf.

Comment: So magnet strength doesn't impact the inductance of the winding? I was always confused about that.